# How to find the best fit for signals

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have Big Data. I have plotted 2 vectors in the figure below, the blue plot represents my ground truth, whereas the purple one is my predicted output.
I want to calculate the optimal A and C, so that it fits ( as A will control its stretch, and C will control it offset).

```
Y_groundTruth = A*(Y_predicted) + C;
```

[image]

I have been trying to manually fit it, moreover another known thing is that the stretch factor (A) also depends on the current value, meaning

When Y_groundTruth is in between 1000 to 1400, it will have a constant value, similarly from 800-900, but this is something which effects my data less, so currently its not the priority.

Comment: Sounds like you want to minimize the sum of squared differences. This is a standard linear optimization. If you've got too much data, just sub-sample it, like every 100th point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i tried solving it using mean sqaured error and least squares approach, used LMS and RLS algorithm, but they would never converge and didnot help much (as I see the data spread (A factor) changes when the value of X is lower and vice versa. Maybe I am doing it wrong, I will double check it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, [ordinary least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation) should be able to solve this problem.

```
Y_predicted = Y_predicted(:);
Y_groundTruth = Y_groundTruth(:);
X = [Y_predicted,ones(size(Y_predicted))];
coeffs = (X'*X)\(X'*Y_groundTruth);

A = coeffs(1);
C = coeffs(2);

mse = sum((Y_groundTruth - (A*Y_predicted + C)).^2)/length(Y_predicted);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried the above method and it gives me an err of 1.06 e10. I tried plotting it and visually it also doesnot look good

Comment: @Omer I was quite careless forgot to bracket `(A*Y_predicted + C)` in the error calculation! Care to try it again? I also notice that the last part of your graph between `9000` and `10000` doesn't look like it can be estimated with a linear fit, so some error is to be expected. Your first prediction sample also looks like it is `0` which might increase the error a little. Maybe try the script on the region [1000,8000] and see if that works?

Comment: @eigenchris: Good one. To fix the zone from 9000 on, a RANSAC-approach could be a good choice. Maybe something from the FEX is applicable, like e.g. [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30809-ransac-algorithm-with-example-of-finding-homography)

Comment: @knedlsepp That's a good idea. RANSAC would be more robust dealing with outliers than simple linear regression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time out, it now gives 2.1e10 error :(. I am trying RANSAC algorithm  and will upload the results

Comment: @Omer: [This](https://github.com/RANSAC/RANSAC-Toolbox) looks even more promising than the FEX-link.

Comment: @David My original post simply had the squared error. It is now the mean squared error after an edit.

Comment: @eigenchris..Hi, plugged it again, now the error is 900.

Comment: @ Knedlsepp yeah I just downloaded the toolbox and trying out its algos thanks for the share